# What's the fastest way to get a range of existing members from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sequence, sparse-matrix

We have an array filled up like so:

```
const arr = [];
arr[3] = 'content3';
arr[4] = 'content4';
arr[6] = 'content6';
arr[7] = 'content7';
```

Now we want to get the existing items starting with index 3, ending with index 6. Here's a naive approach:

```
const slice = arr.slice(3,7); // ["content3", "content4", empty, "content6"]
const cleanSlice = slice.filter(a => a); // ["content3", "content4", "content6"]
```

Is there a way to read the range that does not include the empty members?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter with a callback which returns `true` for every call (to get [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) elements as well). This approach does not visit sparse elements.

```js
const array = [];

array[3] = 'content3';
array[4] = undefined;
array[6] = 0;

const result = array.filter(_ => true);

console.log(result);
```

By taking an object and an array for the range, you could filter the keys and map the values.

```js
const data = {};

data[3] = 'content3';
data[4] = undefined;
data[6] = 0;
data[7] = 'content7';

const range = [3, 6];
const result = Object
    .keys(data)
    .filter(k => k >= range[0] && k <= range[1])
    .map(k => data[k]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where you're collecting the range here.

Comment: maybe an array is simply not the applyable data structure for your problem.

Comment: Yap, that might be the case.